# Firebase Firestore JavaScript: Find document with a field unset

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In Firebase Firestore, can I query for documents that have a specific field unset?

I know if I do

```
collectionReference.where('requires', '==', null)
```

won't do what I want since `null` is fundamentally different. `undefined` is not accepted in the driver. Using `orderBy` doesn't work, it doesn't even return that document with the field unset.

Is there any way to do this query *without* having to set the field to `null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore doesn't support querying for properties/fields that don't exist.  If you think carefully about it: *how do you index something that doesn't exist*?  You need to have some value there, even if it's null, in order for an index to be able to work *at massive scale* to quickly find the things you're looking for.