# Firestore query of a collection of documents in which some field does not exist does not work

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of documents in a Firestore database. All the documents have a field named "debtorEmail", but only some of them have also a field named "creditorEmail". I want to read all the documents in which "creditorEmail" is absent. According to Firestore [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries?hl=en#web-version-9_3):

```
const notCapitalQuery = query(citiesRef, where("capital", "!=", false));
```

This query does not return city documents where the capital field does not exist. Not-equal (!=) and not-in queries exclude documents where the given field does not exist.

My code is as follows:

```
const docCollection = collection(db, "requests");
const dataSection = document.getElementById("data-section");
const qRequests = query(docCollection, where("creditorEmail", "!=", false));
```

but this query delivers precisely those documents in which creditorEmail exists. If I change  "false" by "true" the query delivers the same results. It is as if the "!=" condition does not work. Does anybody have any idea of what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore queries are always based on what information exists about a document in the index using in that query, and if the document doesn't have a field it won't be included in an index on that field.

So what you're seeing is the expected behavior.

Consider giving field a default value, such as an empty string for string fields. That way the document will be present in indexes on/including that field.

Also see:

- [Firebase Firestore JavaScript: Find document with a field unset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49135601/firebase-firestore-javascript-find-document-with-a-field-unset)

---

Update: to test your case, I created a collection `69963042` with three documents:

- `fDmsBjxCdg3xygzjxZo0` with no data in it whatsoever.
- `lxRXLFHoG2NPtC1brv2D` with a `capital` field set to `false`.
- `wnXLanoHLacRoblnJ7wo` with a `capital` field set to `true`.

I then ran three queries:

```
const q = query(
  collection(db, "69963042"),
  where("capital", "!=", false)
);
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  console.log(`${doc.id}: capital=${doc.get("capital")}`)
})
```

This logs:

> "wnXLanoHLacRoblnJ7wo: capital=true"

Changing the condition to `where("capital", "!=", true)`, leads to logging of:

> "lxRXLFHoG2NPtC1brv2D: capital=false"

And finally changing the condition to `where("capital", "==", false)`, leads to logging:

> "lxRXLFHoG2NPtC1brv2D: capital=false"

None of the queries returns the document without the `capital` field, which is working as expected.

For the code, and config for my database in case you want to test yourself, see https://jsbin.com/hudayez/edit?html,console

Comment: I understand, but the problem is the opposite: some of the documents in the collection do not have the field "creditorEmail", but the query "!=", "false" does not exclude them.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the problem. See the code, logging output, and link that I added to my answer. If your problem persists, can you set up a similar reproduction that we can then look at?

Comment: Thank your very much @Frank van Puffelen for your reply. After checking your code I returned to mine to see what was going on, and... surprise.... It seems to be working as expected. I was confused. The query "!=" indeed does exclude the documents that do not have the relevant field. I feel quite embarrassed and I am sorry for the time you spent with this issue. Do you think I should delete the question, since it is meaningless, or should I leave it as a testimony of my confusion?

Comment: No need to delete it. We all make mistakes, and somebody might stumble upon this and benefit from my minimal repro. Going forward, setting up a repro like the one I did can prevent embarrassment, and is the reason we often ask for an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You are right. I was not familiar with the tools to share and execute code as you showed me in the example. Thank you very much for your help.